# ListView binding data set (no database)

Tags: winforms, listview, c#-4.0

Let say, I have ListView, how do I bind/connect it with another data-set?

For example: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poJ5U.png)

A new row added, new default extra data added

A specific row is selected, display extra data

All row selected, display similar data and display *multiple value* if not same

All row selected, change a extra data, all selected row apply new data

A specific row deleted, the extra data also gets deleted.

*this not connected with database, just simple data in the memory*

Answer (score 0):

A standard .NET ListView doesn't support data binding.

You will need to switch to `DataGrid` (which has its own problems) or a data bindable version of `ListView`, like [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-bind-a-dataset-to-an-objectlistview).